# Interact with smart contract to get token ID

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I have a function in my platform that finds out if a user is the holder of a specific token

```
const [tokenId, setTokenId] = useState(false);
```

```
const checkOwners = async () => {
    if (ethereum) {      
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);      
      if (currentAccount !== null && nftContract !== null) {
        let walletOfowners = await nftContract.tokensOfOwner(currentAccount);
        if (walletOfowners.length > 0) {
          setTokenId(true);
        } else {
          setTokenId(false);
        }
      }
    }
};
```

But I want my code to get which tokens (Ids) the connected users hold. Smart contract does have a tokensOfOwner function.

````
 //Returns all IDs owned by a particular holder.
    function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns (uint[] memory) {

        uint tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);

        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++) {
            tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Can you share your smart contract code for `tokensOfOwner`?

Comment: Sure: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x22075F51989522Aa9d6890ac5bA3DC246cAa02A9

Comment: Needs to be shared in the question itself, not as a link

Comment: Just added to the question.

Comment: I don't understand your question now. What exactly is the problem? What is `currentAccount`? Is that not the address of the current user?
Is the problem that your state variable is just a boolean, when it should be an array of tokenIds? 

Just set the entire returned array in state variables, and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the function I needed:

```
  const tokensIdsOfOwner = async () => {
    if (ethereum) {
       const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
       const signer = provider.getSigner();
       const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);        
         if (currentAccount !== null && nftContract !== null) {            
           let ownerTokenId = await nftContract.tokensOfOwner(currentAccount);            
           console.log(ownerTokenId.toString());
           setOwnerIds(ownerTokenId.toString());
         }
    }
  };
```